# How to fix the position of label and table widgets while using Tkinter with scrollbar?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, widget

I have the following code that generates a template using tkinter.

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.title("Template viewer")
root.geometry("1000x600")
root.resizable(False, False)

# Create A Main frame
main_frame = Frame(root)
main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
#main_frame.configure(root,background='red') #overlapped with canvas so background color doesnt work

# Create Frame for X Scrollbar
sec = Frame(main_frame)
sec.pack(fill=X,side=BOTTOM)

# Create A Canvas inside the main frame
my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame,background='blue')
my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH,expand=1)

# Add A Scrollbars to Canvas
x_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(sec,orient=HORIZONTAL,command=my_canvas.xview)
x_scrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
y_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame,orient=VERTICAL,command=my_canvas.yview)
y_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)

# Configure the canvas
my_canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=x_scrollbar.set)
my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=y_scrollbar.set)
my_canvas.bind("<Configure>",lambda e: my_canvas.config(scrollregion= my_canvas.bbox(ALL))) 

# Create Another Frame INSIDE the Canvas
second_frame = Frame(my_canvas)

# Add that New Frame a Window In The Canvas
my_canvas.create_window((0,0),window= second_frame, anchor="nw")

lbltwo=Label(my_canvas, text="this is a template", fg='black', bg = 'red', font=("Helvetica", 16))
lbltwo.place(x=0, y=100, anchor = SW)

##add table to the frame
# Create an object of Style widget
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('clam')

# Add a Treeview widget
tree = ttk.Treeview(my_canvas, column=("FName", "LName"), show='headings', height=5)
tree.column("# 1", anchor=CENTER, stretch=NO, width=490)
tree.heading("# 1", text="Column1")
tree.column("# 2", anchor=CENTER, stretch=NO, width=490)
tree.heading("# 2", text="Column2")

# Insert the data in Treeview widget
tree.insert('', 'end', text="1", values=('Entry1', 'file1'))
tree.insert('', 'end', text="1", values=('Entry2', 'file2'))

tree.place(x=0, y=250)

#add image path
img= (Image.open("/path/to/image/file/"))
resized_image= img.resize((500,400)) #Resize the Image using resize method
new_image= ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)
my_canvas.create_image(500,900,anchor=CENTER, image=new_image) #Add image to the Canvas Items

#Add new rectangles to the canvas items
b1 = my_canvas.create_rectangle(0,600,1000,1100, outline="black")


root.mainloop()
```

It works well without any label or table widgets. But, as I add them they seem to scroll with the canvas and not fixed at their position (top of the page). This makes them overlap the stuff on the bottom of the page. Can anyone suggest how to make these added widgets fixed at specific positions?

Comment: On vertical scrollbar, you can't one scroll for both widget. You need two scrollbar for top verticall and one for  vertical side  bottom. You are mixed them up main_frame, sec and second_frame.. Do one at a time.

Comment: @toyotaSupra I dont think i got them mixed up. I would like to have one single scrollbar for 2-3 widgets which I didnt knew that it cant be done.

Comment: When I execute your code, the label and the treeview are kept at their initial places when I scroll the canvas.  So what is your issue actually?

Comment: @acw1668 the label and the treeeview dont move up with the scrollbar. They overlap with the image position when the scrollbar is moved down

Comment: But what you say in the question is *"how to make these added widgets fixed at specific positions?"*.  If you actually want the opposite, then put them using `my_canvas.create_window(...)` instead of `.place(...)`.

Comment: so create new frame for each widget?  theres already a main canvas in the entire window.

Comment: You can put any tkinter widget into canvas using `.create_window()`.